# Apache: IP addresses vs users

Tags: apache, logging, ip-address, nat

Suppose you wanna analyze your access log files in order to check users activities. One common way is to assume that a same IP address corresponds to a same user.

However, several internet providers use CGNAT. Which, briefly, allows multiple end users to use a common public IP address.
In that case, users behind a CGNAT and sharing the same public address might be confused with each other. Therefore, causing problems to calculate view counts and to ban disruptive traffic.

**Question**
Any alternative to mitigate that?
(Preferably using only Apache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider unique users are unique combinations of IP+user-agent. It would be a bit better but still wouldn't be able to differentiate users on the same IP and using the same browser, on the same platform.

Other than that, you'd need to use a server side scripting technology and track sessions. That would require cookies tho, which is not too much of a biggie. You can't track static assets using that method tho.